# Data is not saved in SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyt7A.png)

I am trying to update data in a SQL Server table. I get a message that data is saved, after a query execution.

But when I check in that table, I find that the data is not saved. Is anything wrong in my query?

I am using SQL Server 2008 and C# for coding.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Inward_Rpt SET Date='" + date + "',Cashier_Name='" + cashier_name + "',Supplier_Code='" + sup_code + "',Supplier_Name='" + name + "',Payment_Mode ='" + p_method + "',Total_Bill='" + tot_bill + "',Total_Paid='" + tot_paid + "',Previous_Due = '" + total_due + "',Current_Due ='" + c_due + "',Remark ='" + remark + "'WHERE Supplier_Name='" + name + "'", con);
cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("Data Saved..");
```

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](https://xkcd.com/327/)

Comment: Can you show us your **connection string** used to connect to SQL Server?

Comment: try to surround this bit of code with `try` and `catch` and put a breakpoint
EDIT: Also you can try  to copy all  `cmd1 ` string to your DB and check if the query has no errors

Comment: Most likely, with the concatenating together your SQL command, something goes wrong - just **don't do it - EVER** - use a **properly parametrized `UPDATE` query** instead!

Comment: What is the value of `"UPDATE Inward_Rpt SET Date='" + date + "',Cashier_Name='" + cashier_name + "',Supplier_Code='" + sup_code + "',Supplier_Name='" + name + "',Payment_Mode ='" + p_method + "',Total_Bill='" + tot_bill + "',Total_Paid='" + tot_paid + "',Previous_Due = '" + total_due + "',Current_Due ='" + c_due + "',Remark ='" + remark + "'WHERE Supplier_Name='" + name + "'"`?

Comment: Run your program through the debugger. Put a breakpoint on the line  `cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();` and have a look at the query that is about to be sent to the DB. If it looks good, then copy-paste it into SSMS directly, and run it. This approach is a lot faster for finding your problem, rather than expecting us to guess for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found your error. Your `WHERE` clause is using the same `name` that you are updating the Supplier Name to. Assuming this is a new name, you will never find the record you want to update. The below code is cleaner, not prone to injection issues, and it should work the way you want.

Note that you will have to provide a new variable to cater to the `name` / `sup_name` situation.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
cmd1.Connection = con;
cmd1.CommandText = @"
    UPDATE Inward_Rpt 
    SET Date = @date 
        , Cashier_Name = @cashier_name
        , Supplier_Code = @sup_code
        , Supplier_Name = @sup_name
        , Payment_Mode = @p_method
        , Total_Bill = @tot_bill
        , Total_Paid = @tot_paid
        , Previous_Due @total_due
        , Current_Due = @c_due
        , Remark = @remark
    WHERE Supplier_Name = @name";

cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", date);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cashier_name", cashier_name);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sup_code", sup_code);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sup_name", sup_name);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p_method", p_method);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tot_bill", tot_bill_name);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tot_paid", tot_paid);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@total_due", total_due);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c_due", c_due);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@remark", remark);
cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);

cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();

MessageBox.Show("Data Saved..");
```

Comment: @ShivvanandPatil Did this help solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Is the All the Fields are String Datatype in your Database Table? Check the Datatypes Because u give Single Quotes for all Data. If the Table Datatype is Number Remove the Single Quotes.

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Inward_Rpt SET Date='" + date + "',Cashier_Name='" + cashier_name + "',Supplier_Code=" + sup_code + ",Supplier_Name='" + name + "',Payment_Mode ='" + p_method + "',Total_Bill='" + tot_bill + "',Total_Paid='" + tot_paid + "',Previous_Due = '" + total_due + "',Current_Due ='" + c_due + "',Remark ='" + remark + "'WHERE Supplier_Name='" + name + "'", con);
```

Comment: no some field data type is int,some are money and date also

Comment: @ShivvanandPatil which are the int datatyes in your Query?

Comment: supplier_code is a int datatype

Comment: @ShivvanandPatil above the answerI put the query run that

Comment: no ..still not updated

Comment: debug the code and check it has any runtime error

Comment: i checked no such a errors,,